# How to control sequence of calls for WWF Receive activities

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have a flowchart with 3 `ReceiveActivity`.

For example
`ReceiveActivity1(StartProcess)->ReceiveActivity2(ApproveByBoss)->ReceiveActivity3(FinalizeProcess)`

Is there any way to "teach" workflow that there is some special behavior (for example Exception thrown) when `FinalizeProcess` method is called via WCF but `ApproveByBoss` was never called for specific workflow instance?

Of course it is possible to drop a custom activity that will verify some "expected" persisted statuses after Receive triggered. But it makes a workflow modification not so flexible I think.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to "teach" workflow that there is some special
>   behavior (for example Exception thrown) when FinalizeProcess method is
>   called via WCF but ApproveByBoss was never called for specific
>   workflow instance?

How can you proceed to `FinalizeProcess` if `ApproveByBoss` is not finished. The WF will throw exception if implemented properly. In order to achieve your requirement you have to use [Correlation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358754.aspx). Check [this nice article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50820/Establishing-Correlation-Between-Multiple-RECEIVE).

Comment: Flowerking, thanks for a suggestion to look at Correlation. In fact I already did it before too, also examined a CodeProject article you suggested and still do not see how using correlation to get an exception when WCF receive activities are called in some invalid order (different order then activities are in a flow). Can you give more certain advice ?

Answer (score 0):

Not without making a mess of your WF. You could however look at this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/routingrules/archive/2009/12/30/routing-service-features-error-handling-part-2.aspx